# Continue downloading even when leave the page

Tags: codenameone

I am using CN1 to developp an application and on one of the pages within the app, there is a download button that triggers a music download from that page and the downloading is working great.

Here is the method i am using to download:

> Util.downloadUrlToFileSystemInBackground()

But the problem is once i leave that page the download stops.
How can i continue downloading even if i leave the page that contains the code of dowload?
thanks

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

That utility method downloads without blocking the UI, if you stay within the app it will continue downloading if you leave the app it will stop...

I'm guessing you want background to work when exiting the app that requires [background fetch](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/background/BackgroundFetch.html).